# Can native ASL signers ID someone’s native sign language from their accent in otherwise fluent ASL?

Tags: second-lang-acquisition, sign-languages, asl

Google keeps trying to give me native accent variations in ASL when I try to look this up, hence asking it here.

In spoken English, it tends to be relatively obvious if someone’s first language is French or Spanish or a Sinitic language: even if their English is otherwise fluent, their native language influences their pronunciations and such. Can a Deaf signer usually identify the native sign language of a Deaf individual who is otherwise fluent in ASL?

Comment: From a BSL perspective: [this 2021 article](https://www.signsolutions.uk.com/are-there-different-accents-in-sign-language); also, [a 2020 paper](https://www.jbe-platform.com/content/journals/10.1075/sll.00050.san) on Al-Sayyid Beduoin SL accents in Israeli SL.

Comment: I can't speak for ASL or foreign accents in SLs generally, but both BSL and PJM (polski język migowy) have regional accents which are easily identified by natives